# drawing a simple hangman design linked to my incorrect guesses in c#

Tags: c#

**I wish to display a simple hangman design using characters from the keyboard** based on the incorrect answers that a user inputs. These incorrect answers will draw a new piece to the hangman each time although i am unsure how to do this. I have made my program function to cycle through 10 guesses before displaying the right answer and looping back to a new word.

**The question i am asking is i do not know how to make a visual representation of a hangman in c# and how to link this to my existing code to only draw specific parts of the hangman based on the incorrect guesses. How do i do this?**

The code is below.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static string RandomWord()
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int response = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            string randWord = "";

            switch (response)
            {
                case 1:

                    randWord = "dog";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    randWord = "robot";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    randWord = "fish";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    randWord = "continue";
                    break;
            }

            return randWord;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value = "";
            int count = 0;
            int gameLoop = 0;
            string inData;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman here is the first word");

            do
            {
                count = 0;
                value = RandomWord();
                char[] newValue = new char[value.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < newValue.Length; i++)
                {

                    newValue[i] = '_';

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < newValue.Length; i++)
                {

                    Console.Write(newValue[i] + " ");

                }

                do
                {

                    count++;
                    Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter your guess  : ");
                    char input = (Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0]);

                    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (value[i] == input)
                        {
                            newValue[i] = input;
                        }

                    }

                    for (int x = 0; x < newValue.Length; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(newValue[x] + " ");


                    }


                    string s = (value);
                    string t = new string(newValue);

                    int c = string.Compare(s, t);
                    if (c == 0)
                    {
                        count = 10;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nCongratulations you guessed the word {0}", value);
                    }



                } while (count < 10);


                string Wrong = (value);
                string Wrong2 = new string(newValue);

                int gameOver = string.Compare(Wrong, Wrong2);
                if (gameOver != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nGame Over! the correct word was {0}", value);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to go again? if so press 1 or 0 to exit");
                inData = Console.ReadLine();
                gameLoop = Convert.ToInt32(inData);

            }
            while (gameLoop == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for?  Is it not behaving as you'd like?  What behavior are you seeing?  It would be helpful to us if you could be a bit more precise about your question, rather than expecting us to read your mind :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how you plan to draw the hangman using ASCII art, but you could create a string array containing the 10 "pictures" as strings and then showing the corresponding one when appropriate.

You can create an array like so:

```
var pictures = new[]{":-)", ":-|", ":-(", "x.x", etc. };
```

and then

```
count++;

// display it here

Console.WriteLine(pictures[count]);

Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter your guess  : ");
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems the right sort of thing, plus where to put it has really helped, i know i shouldn't comment but thank you very much :)

Comment: ok sorry to post again, ive tried this answer you suggested, i get the understanding of it, the only problem is how do i get the previous array top be displayed with the current one?

Comment: what do you mean by array top?

Comment: sorry i misspelled "to". I'm basically asking how to display the previous drawings from the array so if they get a letter wrong for the fourth time it will display the 0th element, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd element from my pictures array

Comment: you can use a `for` loop: `for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) Console.WriteLine(pictures[idx]);`

Comment: this is perfect and works for me, however i'm just having problems arranging the picture as the image is building itself upside down because of the index :( i'm not sure how i can get the head to be displayed as a separate index to the part of the hang post that is inline with it. would learning forms be a lot easier than doing this?